# c# web browser cookies in httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control which loads a page.
I then hit a button to call this method:

```
public void get(Uri myUri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        cookieJar.SetCookies(webBrowser1.Document.Url,webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Replace(';', ','));
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        int cookieCount = cookieJar.Count;

        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        txt.Text = readStream.ReadToEnd();


            txt2.Text = cookieCount.ToString();


    }
```

As from the cookieCount int i can see that if i call the method before logging in on the page in the web browser control i would get 6 cookies, and after i log in i get 7. 
However, even with the cookies the response i get is the same as if i wouldnt have been logged in.
So i am guessing that the cookies isnt being sent with the request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're recreating your CookieContainer every time you call this method, you need to use the same CookieContainer in all requests

you can use this code, to handle your requests:

```
      static CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        static HttpWebRequest GetNewRequest(string targetUrl, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
            request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            return request;
        }

        public static HttpWebResponse MakeRequest(HttpWebRequest request, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
        {


            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5Accept: */*";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string postData = "";
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> parametro in parameters)
                {
                    if (postData.Length == 0)
                    {
                        postData += String.Format("{0}={1}", parametro.Key, parametro.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        postData += String.Format("&{0}={1}", parametro.Key, parametro.Value);
                    }

                }
                byte[] postBuffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                request.Method = "GET";
            }


            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);


            while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
            {
                response.Close();
                request = GetNewRequest(response.Headers["Location"], SessionCookieContainer);
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
            }


            return response;
        }
```

and to request a page,

```
 HttpWebRequest request = GetNewRequest("http://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/login.php?do=login", cookies);
 Dictionary<string,string> parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"your params","as key value"};


            HttpWebResponse response = MakeRequest(request, cookies, parameters);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                if(!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks!
I cant seem to get the syntax for the code to request a page right.
would you wrap in in a method or something please?
I am pretty new to c#.

Comment: here you can see a sample application that do this requests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601621/httpwebrequest-another-page/11601883#11601883

Answer (score 1):

When matching the session, your web server may be taking into account some other [HTTP request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests), besides cookies. To name a few: `User-Agent`, `Authorization`, `Accept-Language`.

Because `WebBrowser` control and `WebRequest` do not share sessions, you'd need to replicate all headers from the `WebBrowser` session. This would be hard thing to do, as you'd need to intercept `WebBrowser` trafic, in a way similar to what [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) does.

A more feasible solution might be to stay on the same session with `WebBrowser` by using [Windows UrlMon APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee318402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like [`URLOpenStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`URLDownloadToFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) etc., instead of `WebRequest`. That works, because `WebBrowser` uses `UrlMon` library behind the scene.

I've recently answered some related questions:

- [The notorious yet unaswered issue of downloading a file when windows security is required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19024794/1768303)
- [Upload a file to a website programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19758767/1768303)